# Read amount of lines from a text file and store them as a constant int for array size c++

Tags: c++, arrays, inputstream, constants

I'm new to C++ and having some problems. Basically what I have to do is read different kinds of text files and use the amount of lines as the size for the rows of a 2-dimensional array.

The input file looks like this:

> int_n1 int_n2 (These are 2 integers needed later on for processing)
>
> (blank line)
>
> [amount of nurses][140] (too much to type out)

link to what it actually looks like here
http://puu.sh/lEh2y/e4f740d30f.png

My code looks like this:

```
//maak inputStream klaar voor gebruik
ifstream prefFile(INPUTPREF);
//test of de inputstream kan geopend worden
if (prefFile.is_open())
{
    // new lines will be skipped unless we stop it from happening:    
    prefFile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

    // count the newlines with an algorithm specialized for counting:
    unsigned line_count = std::count(std::istream_iterator<char>(prefFile),std::istream_iterator<char>(),'\n');

    int aantNurse = line_count + 1 - 2;

    int nursePref[aantNurse][140];
}
```

Of course, just putting 'const' in front of 'int aantNurse' doesn't work.
Does anybody have a suggestion on how to solve this? I'd prefer not to have to use an oversized array that could fit everything, although that could be a possiblity.

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector` of `std::string`s?

Comment: In a later stage, I will need to process all the numbers from the input file in arrays and use them in a genetic algorithm. I believe arrays are more efficient for this, no?

Comment: In order for `aantNurse` to be `const` it has to be initialized when it is declared.  So instead of initializing `line_count` as you do, just initialize a `const int aantNurse`.

Comment: `int nursePref[aantNurse][140];` when `aantNurse` is not a constant expression is not standard C++ (but is supported as an extension in some C++ compilers). The natural C++ way of doing this is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @AnonMail your solution still gave me errors and also it wouldn't be useful as I eventually want to declare the variable outside of the function, still thanks for the reply

Comment: @crashmstr I guess I'll try to make it work with vectors after all, after looking into it should be possible

Comment: That is the `only` way to do it so.   You must have introduced errors - edit you question to show your code changes.  Declaring the variable outside of the function does not preclude you from doing what I've said.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the possible solutions you can allocate memory for your array `nursePref` dynamically and release it in the end.

Just something like this:

```
int** nursePref = new int*[aantNurse];
for (int i = 0; i < aantNurse; ++i) {
    nursePref[i] = new int[140];
}
```

Then release it properly using `delete[]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aantNurse; ++i) {
    delete[] nursePref[i];
}
delete[] nursePref;
```

Also, as it's said already, using vectors is a better idea:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > nursePref(aantNurse, std::vector<int>(140));
```